# Assignment in `for` loop requires explicit indexing?

Tags: python

**TL; DR:** Can this type of loop be rewritten using a `for` loop without explicit indexing?

```py
vals = [0, 1]
for i, _ in enumerate(vals):
    vals[i] += 1
```

and still work as intended, that is increment the elements of `vals`?

---

I know that this does not increment `vals`:

```py
vals = [0, 1]
for v in vals:
    v += 1
```

So am I stuck with the explicit indexing if I want to use a `for` loop?

Comment: `vals = [i + 1 for i in vals]` – also has a `for .. in`… :-3

Comment: You are right I am still thinking in `c++` I guess all Python `for` loops have an `in`. The question (which you answered perfectly) is really about the need for explicit indexing in the loop. I edited the question a bit to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `vals` list would need to consist of *mutable objects*. But since integers aren't mutable, `v += 1` will never mutate the value, and always replace the local variable `v` with a new value, which does not reflect back to the list. You will always have to explicitly replace values in the list. You don't need `enumerate` with the superfluous second value to do so:

```
for i in range(len(vals)):
    vals[i] += 1
```

But the real pythonic solution for this particular situation would be much simpler:

```
vals = [i + 1 for i in vals]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is eqiuvalent to:

```
vals = [i + 1 for i in vals]
```

but if you want to use `enumerate`, this is silly but:

```
vals = [vals[i]+1 for i, _ in enumerate(vals)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to avoid immediate unpacking, you can do

```
vals = [0, 1]
for item in enumerate(vals):
    vals[item[0]] += 1
```

Since you don't need the original value, you can also do

```
vals = [0, 1]
for i in range(len(vals)):
    vals[i] += 1
```

Finally, as @deceze pointed out, you can replace the entire list with a new one by writing a comprehension like

```
vals = [0, 1]
vals = [i + 1 for i in vals]
```

All of these examples avoid multiple assignments in the loop. Keep in mind that the comprehension completely replaces your list. If any other parts of the program rely on the original, they will not be automatically updated.

The issue is that integers are immutable, so `+= 1` actually creates a new integer and assigns it to the list. If you want to keep the original list reference, you'll have to do explicit indexing.

Answer (score -1):

[You can read about exactly why this doesn't work like you think it does in the Python reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

However, to do what you seem to want to do, I think that *list comprehension* is a nice, concide, Pythonic way. For example:

```
new_values = [(x + 6) for x in your_list]
```

Comment: The source you linked to does not really explain anything